# Custom URL flask

Tags: python, flask, url

I need to know if it is possible to create a URL with flask like this `https://123456789@localhost/api` in order to identify the user who is using the API.
With `123456789` the customer ID I need to check.

Comment: I would use [jwt tokens](https://jwt.io/introduction) for that. so that user id is not seen in the URL

Answer (score 0):

With flask [blueprint](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/) you can create something like this url `https://localhost/api/<user>`

Answer (score 0):

It is.

An URL like `http://123456789@localhost/api` gets translated to just `http://localhost/api` with an [HTTP Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) header like `Authorization: Basic MTIzNDU2Nzg5Og==` (where `MTIzNDU2Nzg5Og==` is the base64 encoding of `123456789`).

This is accessible via [`request.authorization`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/wrappers/#authentication).[`username`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.Authorization.username).